# ASCII number for "space" is not being detected

Tags: java

Simple password maker

```
Random myrand = new Random();
int x = myrand.nextInt(126);
x = x+1;
char c = (char)x;
//this gets the character version of x
for (int mycounter = 0; mycounter < 10; mycounter++)
{
  x = myrand.nextInt(127);
  x = x+1;
  if (x == 32)
  {
   x = 33;
  }
  c = (char)x;
  System.out.print(c);
  }
 System.out.println();
```

Where is my error?

How do I fix this?

Comment: I suspect you're seeing other non-printable characters... you probably don't want anything below 33.

Comment: Well, what's the problem with the code you have now? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: `x = x + 1;` => `x++` or `x += 1;`, if you like!

Comment: 1. How do I make it above 33? 
2. It makes a simple password of 9-11 characters. I am not sure exactly how many. Sorry!

Comment: C. Lang - Where do I put the X++?

Comment: @C.Lang: That's just a stylistic choice, but it makes no difference to what the OP is actually talking about.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I know this. That's why it says "...if you like!" Anyway am I the only person who's not allowed to comment without it being specific to the solution. See a million other comments on a million other posts.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I really needed the help! I am just beginning Java, and think I know more than I do. I have no idea why I am telling you this!

Comment: @user2411568: as @Jon Skeet has pointed out, I was pointing out an option which won't change the current operation of the code. If you do use it, you just replace the `x = x + 1` with `x++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're detecting the space character, but what about *other* characters which aren't printable? I wouldn't expect anything lower than ASCII 32 to be useful as a password.

I suspect you want something like:

```
// Remove bit before the loop which used x and c. It was pointless.
Random myrand = new Random();
for (int mycounter = 0; mycounter < 10; mycounter++)
{
    // Range [33, 127)
    int x = myrand.nextInt(127 - 33) + 33;
    char c = (char) x;
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Rather than map "everything non-printable" to a single character, the code above just avoids picking it in the first place, by restricting the range further.

Comment: Thank you Jon! It works! (You probably already knew that, didn't you :)).